# Airport Extreme Wifi Router worked fine with roadrunner at one location, but not AT&T at another.

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

The Airport Extreme was set up in my home with Time Warner's fiber network.  I have now moved, and my provider is AT&T.

I've had a Netgear WGR614 v9 working at this location for years.

When I connect my Extreme, it shows a green light for about 15 seconds then starts blinking orange and will not connect to the AT&T network.

My ISP will not try to help me solve this problem whatsoever.  The manual, Apple.com site, nor searching for this problem on the 'net has given me even a "hint" at what the problem is.

Anyone have ideas?  Would appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you have the Airport physically set up?  Is it plugged into the Netgear router, or directly into the ISP modem?

Comment: When the AirPort Extreme is blinking yellow, you can use the AirPort Utility to see what problem(s) it is reporting. It would help immensely if you could update your Question to include that info (if it's reporting more than one problem, include them all).

Comment: The exact model and firmware version of the AirPort Extreme might help as well. In the current AirPort Utility for Mac, you can find the model by hovering over the name of the base station in the little popover window that comes up when you click on the base station icon in the network map view.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when I moved a few years back and didn't want to pay for their modem when I had a good one.  AT&T does not make it easy to connect unless you are using their modem.  If you are trying to use the Airport as your modem you'll have to edit your settings in the modem menu.  AT&T's DSL settings (at least here) are:

ATM CIRCUIT ID: VP1=0 VCI=35  ATM ENCAPSULATION:  Bridged LLC   ATM PVC Search: Enabled
Internet:  PPoE   DSL PROTOCOL:  G.DMT ANNNEX A   INTERNET ADDRESS:  75.54.80.251   DSL SUBMASK:  255.255.255.255     You also have to enter your ISP Username and a password, obviously.

No other settings should be enabled, no matter how well they worked on TW's system.

Not sure of the differences for Hi-speed as I've never lived where I could get it.  If you have a friend or neighbor on the same setup ask to view the settings in their modem.

If you're airport was setup as the modem but isn't now then be sure to reconfigure for router.

Good luck with it,
bem

Comment: AirPort base stations have never had built-in broadband (DSL or cable) modems, and it looks like neither did the Netgear WGR614.